# SQL first value by group

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, create-table

In a table like this

```
acc_id   time   approved_amount   balance
 11       Jan14     580             500
 11       Feb14     580             400
 11       Mar14     580             300
 11       Apr14     580             200
 22       Jan14     .               800
 22       Feb14     .               700
 22       Mar14     .               600
```

I want to create a column `orig_amount` that would be equal to `approved_amount` if this is not null and to the first value of balance - to balance at `time = min(time)` by `acc_id` if `approved_amount` is null.

Therefore the desired output would look like this:

```
acc_id   time   approved_amount   balance   orig_amount
 11       Jan14     580             500        580
 11       Feb14     580             400        580
 11       Mar14     580             300        580
 11       Apr14     580             200        580
 22       Jan14     .               800        800
 22       Feb14     .               700        800
 22       Mar14     .               600        800
```

I have now this

```
create table second_table as
   select *,
      coalesce(approved_amount, case when time = min(time) then 
       balance end ) as orig_amount
   from first_table
   group by acc_id
   order by acc_id, time;
```

But still not the desired result. Can anybody help please?

Comment: I mean the value of `balance` for which `time = min(time)` by `acc_id`. Therefore, for the first account is is 500 and for the second account it is 800.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `first_value()` window function and `coalesce()`.

```
SELECT acc_id,
       time,
       approved_amount,
       balance,
       coalesce(approved_amount,
                first_value(balance) OVER (PARTITION BY acc_id
                                           ORDER BY time)) orig_amount
       FROM first_table;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=2beb2534d5888a4cc7b4c5ac530c52a0)